# Huge Performance Difference with HashSet between .NET Framework 4.8 and .NET 5

Tags: .net, performance, hashset, .net-5, .net-4.8

I have the problem where the application is very slow because there are events with thousands of handlers attached to it and removing those handlers is really slow. My application runs as .NET Framework 4.8 process,

I wrote a test Programm (but with .NET 5) where I replaced the event with an own implementation where I used a HashSet to store the handlers and implement the add / remove handlers of the event by myself.

My test application worked great, but after applying this solution to my real application, the performance was still bad.

I than realized that the runtime difference seems to be the reason. The following sample program runs fast (approx. 1 second  on .NET 5, but runs several minutes if run the same code in a .NET Framework 4.8 Application):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;

namespace EventPerformaneMeasurement
{
    class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            var sw = new Stopwatch();
            var mc = new MyClass();
            var list = Enumerable.Range(1, 1_000_000).Select(x => new PropertyChangedEventHandler((_, _) => { Console.WriteLine($"Handler {x} called"); })).ToList();
            
            sw.Restart();
            list.ForEach(handler=>mc.PropertyChangedNew += handler); 
           
            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            
            sw.Restart();
            list.ForEach(handler=>mc.PropertyChangedNew -= handler); 
            
            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        }
    }

    class MyClass
    {
        private HashSet<PropertyChangedEventHandler> _handlers = new();
        
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChangedNew
        {
            add => _handlers.Add(value);
            remove => _handlers.Remove(value);
        }
    }
}
```

I created two .NET fiddles to reproduce this behavior, the .NET fiddle required me to change the syntax of my sample code a little bit and to reduce from 1000000 to 15000 iterations, but the performance difference is still visible:

- [.NET 4.7.2](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2Gxm3j)
- [.NET 5](https://dotnetfiddle.net/eVdtZc)

I can't believe that there is a such big difference between .NET 5 and .NET Framework 4.x regarding HashSet performance.

Does anyone know more about this effect or where I'm maybe stuck? Is there a way to get the same   performance in .NET 4.8 with another way?

Comment: You should start from the fact that .NET Core/.NET 5 is much faster and lightweight than .NET Framework in multiple areas, since big portions were rewritten from scratch. Not sure if too much can be done here

Comment: Are you running it without debugger attached? (Ctrl+F5 from visual studio)

Comment: I tested without a debugger, so no debugger was attached. And if you look at the two fiddles, you see approx. a factor 4000, so 2ms vs. 8 seconds! I am very surprised that this use case in .NET Framework should be so slow...

Comment: HashTable critically depends on a good GetHashCode() implementation.  Compare [.NETCore](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/a70005f4d89e03622b4dd3bea058f102e60702af/src/coreclr/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Delegate.CoreCLR.cs#L158) to [.NETFramework](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/delegate.cs,191).  Note the bug fix and the less than ideal workaround, GetType().GetHashCode() is awful as it gives every delegate object the same hash code.  It was probably on their need-to-fix list, changing the implementation for .NETFramework is too risky.

Comment: Hello Hans, thank you. Your answer ist correct. It does not solve my problem but it answers my question if it is really possible that such a performance problem exists in .NET Framework. If you put your comment as answer, I will mark it as correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

In this case and since I cannot wait until we can switch with our product to .NET 5, I will need to refactor to not use events / delegates, and instead use the [Oberserver](https://dotnettutorials.net/lesson/observer-design-pattern/) pattern with interfaces and add / remove listener methods. Such observer objects will not have such weak GetHashCode implementations, so HashSet will perform with such observer objects...